# How to make a carriage return in the POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use the apache-poi to generate a csv document. But I have a problem when I do this in my code:

```
/**
 * @param builder
 */
private void ajoutLigne(StringBuilder builder) {
    builder.append("\\n");
}
```

I don't have a carriage return in my doc.

How to make a carriage return in the POI API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a carriage return:

```
builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 1):

so add a carriage return...

```
builder.append("\\r\\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear to me from your question. Though there may be two possibilities

Suppose you have two String str1 and str2 then if you use "\n" then it will be like

`str1 \n str2` that I do not think you want to do.

if you want to use it like

`str1`

`str2`

then you should use just "\n"